# LAG Function in Windows Functions

Tags: google-bigquery, partition-by

I have this query to know the status of customers. To know if the customers was active or not active
I have got this error in BIGQUERY :" Window framing clause is not allowed for analytic function lag" but i don't know who i can make this without"LAG" function

```
 SELECT
  id,
  buyer_company_id,
  delivery_month
      (CASE
          WHEN status = 'recurrent' AND LAG(status,1) OVER(PARTITION BY buyer_company_id ORDER BY buyer_company_id, delivery_month RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) = 'churned' THEN 'active'
          WHEN status = 'churned'
        AND LAG(status,1) OVER(PARTITION BY buyer_company_id ORDER BY buyer_company_id, delivery_month RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) = 'churned' THEN 'not_active'
        ELSE
        status
      END
        ) AS status
    FROM customers_table
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data of your table and the expected result?

Comment: The part should be `lag(status) OVER(PARTITION BY buyer_company_id ORDER BY buyer_company_id, delivery_month)` the  part `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` is not allowed with `lag` or `lead` functions. In case you need to limit the range, please use `first_value` or `last_value`.